# How can I read a .csv file with "" as quotechar with pd.read_csv()?

Tags: python, pandas, str-replace, read.csv

I have a .csv file that I am trying to read in a pd data frame that has the following structure:

```
ID,letter,amount
29,""a,b,c"",34
35,""d,e,f"",21
42,""g,h,i"",67
```

I first tried to read the file, replace in each line "" with " and then write to another file. However, the following code does not change anything:

```
with open(os.getcwd() + "/test.txt") as in_file, open(os.getcwd() + "/test_out.txt",'w+') as out_file:
    lines = in_file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line.replace('""', '"')
        out_file.write(line)
```

I then tried to change the quotechar parameter in the pd.read_csv() function but `data = pd.read_csv(filepath_bd_out, sep = ',', quotechar = '""')` gives me an error because it can only be a 1-character string.

Does anyone know why the replace function fails or how I can solve this?

Comment: `out_file.write(line.replace('""', '"'))`. `str.replace` returns a copy, it doesn't change the original string.

Comment: How did the file get written like that? It's not standard CSV format, and the Python CSV module has no support for it.

Comment: All the answers to similar questions suggest writing code to convert the double delimiters to a single one.

Comment: @IgnatiusReilly Thanks! I completely forgot about that for a second. It works now :)